# Detect if HTML5 video volume property is read-only?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video

I have a mute button that sets my video volume to 0:

```
video.volume = 0;
```

If this isn't supported I'd like to hide the mute button. I can use user-agent detection, but that is less than ideal. Does anyone know of a way to check if this property is read-only?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: did you ever find a solution? thanks

Answer (score 2):

to mute use `.muted`. The old volume will be remembered and it works everywhere.

```
video.muted = true;
```

Comment: wow not sure how that did not come up while googling. thanks!